# Python Import NameError

Tags: python, import, flask

I have a flask application structured like so:

```
/public_html
    /content
        /accounts
            __init__.py
            /classes
                __init__.py
                mycode.py
            /forms
                __init__.py
                myform.py
            /routes
                __init__.py
                myroute.py
        /activity
        /comments
        /media
        /messages
        ...
        __init__.py
    /media
    __build__.py
    __config__.py
```

The **init** in public_html/content looks something like this:

```
from accounts.classes.mycode import *
from accounts.forms.mycode import *
from accounts.routes.mycode import *
#..... etc .... until I've imported all the packages
```

and in each file, like mycode.py I have a circular import back to content like so:

```
from content import *
#The rest of my code goes here.
```

It has worked well for me but I've run into a bit of an issue structuring the rest of the imports as I need to call modules from say: `accounts.routes.mycode`
before it is actually imported. As a result I end up getting `NameError: global name 'functionincode' is not defined`.

I can fix the problem temporarily by importing the different functions at times there is no conflict but my code is becoming nasty. I really don't want to have this big mess of imports that all depend on one another in a specific order.

Is there any way I can go about re-structuring the imports so that there won't be a conflict? I was thinking in each package, like `content.accounts` having the **init**.py import everything there then in each `accounts.classes.mycode.py` importing everything else like:

```
from accounts import *
from activity import *
etc ...
```

However I am hopeful that there will be a bit of an easier fix.

Thanks!

Comment: You should not be using import * at all.

Comment: Which way would be a better way to import :/?

Comment: hand pick what you need from that lib like `from accounts import get_info`, or if you require all, then just `import accounts`

Comment: Ahh I like the idea however I need to import keyword from the content/__init__.py. For example, in routes, @app... is used to declare a route, I need app defined to use it.

Comment: If all of your packages contain `__init__.py` and `mycode.py`, why not just place the code inside `__init__.py`? Better yet, why not just use modules instead (e.g., `accounts/classes.py`, `accounts/forms.py`)?

Comment: By using `from module import *` you are opening yourself up to name conflicts. I suspect that may be part of the confusion. If you use `import module` instead, you can avoid the naming conflict.